# Rails model attributes hidden by default in form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and working through a tutorial. I have created a scaffold and a db, but when I run my site the model attributes are hidden (only one). Is this an issue I can fix or a biproduct of a bad setup?

```
$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

I've tried this a few (underestimate) times so I have added a step to remove the prev db

```
$ bundle exec rake db:drop
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate

$ rail s
```

When I visit /users/new/

I see a form without input fields. Any idea why this is?

When I go into the html of the page it says that the attribute name is hidden, but there is no sign of email.

Any ideas?

**Response to Comments**

users/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131104084139) do

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: can you show your /users/_form.html.erb partial?

Comment: @rb512 I added the _form.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have either name or email input fields in your form, hence you see a blank form.

Add the following before `<div class="actions">`

```
<p>
 <%=f.label :name%>
 <%=f.text_field :name%>
</p>
<p>
 <%=f.label :email%>
 <%=f.text_field :email%>
</p>
```

Comment: undefined method `name' for #<User id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>          It has to do with the first f.text_field :name%> line

Comment: do you have name and email fields? did you run the migrations?  what does your User table look like?

Comment: I think I added it to the question. schema.rb is the tables, correct?

Comment: you don't have those fields.  run the migrations again, make sure, your table has those fields and come back.

Comment: Fixed, I destroyed my scaffold and recreated a new one. Thanks for the help